# Инициализация CustomView

Tags: objective-c, macos, customview

Не могу разобраться с `CustomView`. Я переношу на форму объект `CustomView` в IB. Создаю новый класс для управления `CustomView`, указываю в свойстве `Custom class` мой созданный класс. Далее перезаписываю в файле имплементации класса метод `initWithFrame`. Но программа при запуске не заходит в этот метод. Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инициализации из IB вызывается -`initWithCoder:` Также вы можете воспользоваться методами `awakeAfterUsingCoder:` и `awakeFromNib`, которые автоматически вызываются следом за ним. Также не забудьте задать для вьюшки имя вашего кастомного класса во вкладке Identity inspector в IB.